# 2960 L2 Switch Alteon 4408 problem

Tags: cisco, load-balancing

network topology

L3Switch<->2960<->Alteon

```
         |
     Real Server1
     Real Server2
```

The topology has a 2 real servers and the alteon sitting off the 2960 switch. The 2960 is connected to a L3 switch which provides connectivity outside the subnet. These servers are service the LAN and not the public.

The problem arises when i try to connect to the VIP the browser hangs and I lose connection to the Alteon as well as all the other servers hanging off the 2960 switch. once i shut down the 2960 interface connected to the alteon everything comes back up again.

Can someone take a look at the config and advise

2960 port connecting to LB config

```
description ALteon
switchport access vlan 30
switchport mode access
spanning-tree portfast
spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```

Alteon port connected to switch

```
/c/port 1
        name "SERVER LAYER"
        pvid 30
        iponly e
```

Alteon config

```
/c/port 1
        name "SERVER LAYER"
        pvid 30
        iponly e
/c/port 2
        dis
/c/l2/vlan 1
        name "NETWORK"
        learn ena
        def 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
/c/l2/vlan 30
        ena
        name "SERVER VLAN"
        learn ena
        def 1
/c/l2/stg 1/off
/c/l2/stg 1/clear
/c/l2/stg 1/add 1 30
/c/sys/sshd/on
/c/l3/if 1
        ena
        ipver v4
        addr 192.32.61.200
        mask 255.255.254.0
        broad 192.32.62.255
        vlan 30
/c/l3/gw 1
        ena
        ipver v4
        addr 192.32.61.1
/c/l3/ip/rearp 30
/c/l3/vrrp/on
/c/l3/vrrp/vr 1
        ena
        ipver v4
        vrid 1
        if 1
        prio 101
        addr 192.32.61.81
        preem dis
        share dis
        track
                ifs e

/c/slb
        on
/c/slb/adv
        direct ena
/c/slb/sync
        prios d
/c/slb/real 2
        dis
        ipver v4
        rip 192.32.61.82
        tmout 4
        retry 3
        restr 3
        name "server01"
        addport 80
/c/slb/real 3
        ena
        ipver v4
        rip 192.32.61.83
        tmout 4
        retry 3
        restr 3
        name "server02"
        addport 80
/c/slb/group 1
        ipver v4
```

Comment: Switch port config looks fine; must be something with the Alteon

Answer (score 0):

Further to this when the load balancer is live on the network now. The real IP's have not been assigned to any devices.

If further info is needed let me know